# Comma before "by integrating..."

Tags: british-english, commas

> This  study presents a novel statistical approach for detecting
> disparities on different levels in the economy**,** by integrating AC and UF analytical methods.

Should I use a comma before "by integrating..."?

Comment: It's better to omit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit the comma because there is no need for it. The meaning is clear even without the comma and it feels out of place just like *"My friend Cleo, is a wonderful singer." (incorrect)*

You can refer to https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/ to get a better understanding.